# phpBB3 - handling user entering forum

Tags: phpbb3

I need to notify external script each time somebody logs in to the forums. Where should I call the notification function to handle both user logging in via the login form, AND the one who has just entered forums but has previously logged with "remember me" checked?

michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the function login_box inside of functions.php in the includes directory.  Hopefully this helps!